# Line of Sight CoreLocation or CoreMotion

Tags: swift, core-location, core-motion

what is the best method to get the line of sight (direction of the iPhone)?

I have implement one with CoreLocation:

```
   func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    self.currentDegreesLOS = newHeading.magneticHeading

    if (newHeading.headingAccuracy > 0) { 
        if self.currentDegreesLOS < 135.0 && self.currentDegreesLOS > 45.0 {

                self.currentDegreesLOS = 90.0
            }
                //South direction
            else if self.currentDegreesLOS < 45.0 ||  self.currentDegreesLOS > 315.0 {

                self.currentDegreesLOS = 360.0
            }
                //West direction
            else if self.currentDegreesLOS > 225.0 && self.currentDegreesLOS < 315.0 {

                self.currentDegreesLOS = 270.0
            }
                //North direction
            else if self.currentDegreesLOS > 135.0 &&  self.currentDegreesLOS < 225.0{

                self.currentDegreesLOS = 180.0
            }
    }
  }
```

But whit this I get one the first try 360° by holding the device to the north direction. If I test this on a second run, I will get 180° or 270° for the same direction.

The other solution I tried is one with CoreMotion, but there I have the same problem:

```
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(queue, withHandler: { (data, error) -> Void in

    self.quat = data?.attitude.quaternion

        //Possibility 1
        var attitude:CMAttitude = (data?.attitude)!
        var rm:CMRotationMatrix = attitude.rotationMatrix

        // Get the heading.
        var heading = M_PI + atan2(rm.m22, rm.m12)

        heading = heading*180/M_PI
        if( heading < 0 ){
            heading += 360.0;// convert negative to positive angles

        }
        })
```

Does anybody know how I can get best result with one of the methods above?

Comment: So, in the first example, have you actually paid attention to the raw values you're getting for `magneticHeading`?  Or have you just looked at the values after running it through your additional logic?  And have you looked at the Core Location documentation on this sort of thing?

Comment: I have looked at both values. The raw values are affected with the same problem. In the documentation I have found nothing about this.

Comment: What sort of raw values are you getting?  What sort of raw values are you expecting?  What does the documentation say *exactly* about magnetic heading?  Based on the documentation, are the raw values about what you'd expect?  If not, why not?  This question needs a lot more effort, etc.  The current form of this question is "I have no idea what I'm doing.  Write my code for me."

Comment: Have you, for example, read [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/GettingHeadings/GettingHeadings.html) which is the number one Google result when searching the phrase `"corelocation magnetic heading"` and moreover, have you calibrated the device?  The magnetic heading is calculated with.... magnetics.... and is heavily effected by magnetic things beyond just the earth's magnetosphere (or whatever it is that makes compasses point north).

Comment: For the calibration I have added the delegate method for calibration: locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration(manager: CLLocationManager). But this method will not be called! So based on the documentation the heading accuracy is ok!